# WIX: I don't know why i need to use component/@win64

Tags: wix, 32bit-64bit, platform

I am making a windows installer using wix 3.9.

My current issue is to separate installer to 32 bit and 64 bit using one .wxs file.

More specifically, I want to make 64-bit file replace 32-bit file in 64-bit installer.

So, I tried the following code.

```
  <Component Id="comp_test.pdf" Guid="{A57AD3FC-1C8E-4A4D-8BDA-163DE7659C73}">
    <File Id="file_test.pdf" KeyPath="yes" Source="F:\test\test.pdf" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="comp_test_64.pdf" Guid="{5EF36A6E-19A0-43DE-99A1-9600D5DA412E}" Win64="yes">
    <File Id="file_test_64.pdf" KeyPath="yes" Source="F:\test.pdf" />
  </Component>
```

I expected the 'file_test_64.pdf' replace the 'file_test.pdf' in 64-bit installer.

However, it wasn't even compiled.

If component/@win64 doesn't allow to replace 32-bit file, why we use win64 element?

As I know, 64-bit installer allows to install win64="no" components.

Is there any reason to use component/@win64?

Also how to replace files depending on installer platform type without using condition?